# Iterate through a list while skipping the item on next iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a hard time correctly describing my problem, which is why I haven't found a solution while I'm 100% sure there is one out there... So please don't get angry at me if my question in't unique.
So below, I've tried describing what I need to do. Basically iterate trough a list whilst skipping the item on next iteration. the item that's skipped is the item in the for loop.

```
list = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5]
item1+item2 => item1+item3 => item1+item4 => item1+item5

next iteration

item2+item3 => item2+item4 => item2+item5

next iteration

item3+item4 => item3+item5

last iteration

item4+item5
```

Comment: Why people down vote me? What did I did wrong?

Comment: You might want to check how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is exactly what `itertools.combinations` does, see @blhsing's answer. You don't even need nested for-loops.

Comment: @smci it's not just about solving the problem at hand but also learning. From itertools.combinations I'd just be getting solution without understanding how. With solution from yatu I've learned something new!

Comment: @XelaGreb: Welcome to SO. Sure, but you can always inspect the source code of standard-library functions to see what they do, and they will almost always be more performant. Nested loops are slow. Just as long as you're aware of all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using a list comprehension:

```
[i + j for ix, i in enumerate(l) for j in l[ix+1: len(l)]]
```

Checking on a simple example:

```
l = [4,2,1,4,2]

[i + j for ix, i in enumerate(l) for j in l[ix+1: len(l)]]

[6,  5,   8,   6,   3,   6,   4,   5,   3,   6]
4+2  4+1 4+4  4+2  2+1  2+4  2+2  1+4  1+2  4+2
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! I just need to make it work with error handeling now...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
print(list(map('+'.join, combinations(lst, 2))))
```

This outputs:

```
['item1+item2', 'item1+item3', 'item1+item4', 'item1+item5', 'item2+item3', 'item2+item4', 'item2+item5', 'item3+item4', 'item3+item5', 'item4+item5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
_list = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5] 
for i in range(len(_list)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(_list)):
        print(_list[i],_list[j])
```

> Don't use built-in names and keywords as variable name.